# Can't understand why this equation doesn't return right value of cos x

Tags: trigonometry

Information: `tan(-x) = 2` and `-π < x < 0`

I am asked to calculate the exact value of `cos(3π + x) - 2sin(π/2 + x)`.

First I concluded that tan x = -2 and also that the expression I am given in the problem is equal to: `-3cosx`. After that I solved the equation `-2 = sin x / cos x`. I know that it would be easier to use the other formula which only requires `tan` and `cos` but I wanted to try it this way. However, I can't seem to get the right answer. I get `cos x = 3` (which is impossible) or `cos x = -1` which, in this case, is also impossible as `tan` is negative and so is `sin` which means `cos` has to be a value between 0 and 1(according to the exercise). So I was just wondering why I couldn't get the right value for `cos x` which, by the way, is `√5 / 5`. Does it have anything to do with the fact that `cos x` must be different than 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to add more details of how you get $\cos x = 3$. We have to see your working to find your mistake

Comment: @gt6989b you mean you can see  how $\cos x =3$ is obtained?

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos (x+3 \pi )-2 \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=-3\cos x$$

In the interval $(-\pi,\;0)$ we have:
$$\cos x=\sqrt{\frac{\cos ^2 x}{\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tan^2 x+1}}$$

As $\tan x=-2$

the given expression is $$-3\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tan^2 x+1}}=\color{red}{-\frac{3}{\sqrt 5}}$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If $y = \sin x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\sqrt{1-y^2} = \cos x$ so you are solving
$$
-2 = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
$$
which implies $y < 0$ and also that
$$
1 - y^2 = \frac{y^2}{4} \Rightarrow y^2 = \frac{4}{5} \Rightarrow y = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$